# bridge-utils "add bridge failed: Package not installed"

Tags: linux, arm

I have cross compiled bridge-utils for ARM.
But, while executing, "brctl addbr ", I am getting error:

```
add bridge failed: Package not installed
```

I have no clue about its dependencies.

Answer (score 9):

Probably your kernel is compiled with CONFIG_BRIDGE=n.

Comment: Can you give any information about how to solve this?